# If/Else Conditional not running the second time I call the function

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I run the function the first time, either condition will work. But when I run the function a second time, the new value of "cute" will not change the background image.

```
$("#sbmt-button").click(newImage);

function newImage(){
    event.preventDefault();
    var cute = $("#cute").val();
    $("#cute").val(" ");

   if (cute == "kittens") {
      $("body").attr("class", "kittens");
        console.log(cute);
    } else if (cute == "puppies"){
       $("body").attr("class", "puppies");
      console.log(cute);

    } 
}
```

http://codepen.io/ElaineM/pen/jbYbwj

Comment: Your code works fine.  But note you're clearing out the value with a space, so when you type in the box again, you're probably entering `" kittens"` or `" puppies"`, so it doesn't match either of your conditions.

Comment: Your code works fine *if the user backspaces the space you put in the text box*. The give away should be that your place holder doesn't reappear. So set the value to an empty string (as johnnyRose suggests) instead of a single space, or else trim your `cute` value to remove extra spaces (which probably isn't a bad idea anyway). Or better yet, if you are picking between a set of *defined* values (like `kittens` and `puppies`) use a select control rather than relying on the user to type *exactly what you expect*. For example, if I type `Kittens`, your code doesn't work.

Answer (score 5):

Your code actually works, but only thing is you need to use `$("#cute").val("");` instead of `$("#cute").val(" ");`, which puts a space and it doesn't match the values.

Also, you may try doing the comparison this way by trimming the empty spaces:

```
function newImage(){
    event.preventDefault();
    var cute = $("#cute").val().trim();
    $("#cute").val(" ");

   if (cute == "kittens") {
      $("body").attr("class", "kittens");
        console.log(cute);
    } else if (cute == "puppies"){
       $("body").attr("class", "puppies");
      console.log(cute);

    } 
}
```

Comment: But I typed `PUPPIES` (because I'm really excited about puppies) and it didn't work! Probably best to use a case-insensitive comparison.

Answer (score 2):

The line `$("#cute").val(" ");` puts a space in the text box. What you want is an empty string: `$("#cute").val("");`

Replacing it with an empty string seems to give you your desired output.

Answer (score -1):

**PROBLEM**

You need to use event object `e` passed to event handler as an argument, otherwise your `button` acts as a submit button and the page gets refreshed.

**SOLUTION**

Use the following code instead:

```
function newImage(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var cute = $("#cute").val();
    console.log(cute);        

    if (cute === "kittens") {
       $("body").attr("class", "kittens");
    } else if (cute === "puppies"){
       $("body").attr("class", "puppies");
    } 

    // Reset input
    $("#cute").val("");
}
```

**EXAMPLE**

See [updated example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xwpMvb) for demonstration.